# How to execute statement if a signal is called in C

Tags: c, signals

I'm attempting to free a bit of memory if (^C) signal is called. I haven't been successful using an 'if' statement. I'm probably ignorant of what is really going on, but I could really use some help on this one.

```
while ((line = readline(prompt))) {

    if (signal(SIGINT, sigintHandler) == SIG_IGN){

        free(line); //Trying to execute statement
        continue;
    }
```

Comment: It seems that you are expecting the return value `signal` to tell you whether the signal has occurred. This is not the case. Instead, set up a signal handler function _before_ the loop, and in that function set the value of a global variable to indicate it has been called. Then, inside the loop, check the value of that variable. (Warning: This is a complex topic, it is not possible to cover all the details here.)

Comment: readline library already handles SIGINT etc. to free a previous buffer, and does the looping for you..  have a look at http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/readline/rlman_43.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `signal` *once* before your loop to install the signal handler.  The signal handler itself will be executed when the signal is received.

```
volatile sig_atomic_t interrupt_flag_set = 0;

void sigintHandler( int sig )
{
  interrupt_flag_set = 1;
}

/**
 * Save the original interrupt handler in case you need to 
 * restore it later.
 */
void (*oldhandler)(int) = signal( SIGINT, sigintHandler );
...
while( (line = readline( prompt )) )
{
  if ( interrupt_flag_set )
  {
     // process interrupt
  }
  else
  {
    // process line normally
  }
}
...
/**
 * restore the original interrupt handler.
 */
signal( SIGINT, oldhandler );
```

If you intend your signal handler to catch signals originating from the operating environment (i.e., users hitting Ctrl-C or timers expiring or something like that), then your signal handlers shouldn't do much more than set a flag.  Calling library functions other than `abort`, `_Exit`, `quick_exit`, or `signal` with the received signal value leads to undefined behavior.

I can tell you from personal experience that calling `printf` from a signal handler is *bad* juju.  I worked on a program that periodically wrote to an Access database.  There was a signal handler that was *supposed* to write a message to standard output, but when triggered it wound up writing over the .mdb file, hosing the database beyond repair.